# Memory and performance benefits of using Rails API-only Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

We have an existing Rails application most of whose views we recently ported to a front-end framework living outside of our app. Our rails app mostly serves JSON now.

We are considering porting the rest of our app to api-only as well, and converting it to `Rails 5's` new API-only mode if this will give us any memory usage or performance benefits.

Has anyone else had experience porting their apps to `api-only` and and seeing any memory/performance benefits?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can choose Non-Rails frameworks for API-only service. there is a microframework called [traim](https://github.com/travisliu/traim). It helps you turn your existing Active Record models into a RESTful API service. In hundreds of lines of code, you can easily customize any functionality as you want and without unnecessary overhead for better memory/performance benefits.